# Spring mvc 3 with hibernate 3 how to retrieve or bind to depended entities with foreign key

Tags: hibernate, jquery, spring-mvc

I have two entity and Main(User) entity is in relation with other entity. Now I have form and for that I have split the entities. I have dynamic row ,those columns which are dynamic I have kept them in one separate entity and given relationship with the main entity.  For static row I have one entity.

How should I insert for multiple row in controller?

My entities are like these :

```
package hib.test;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class POSSales implements Serializable {

private Integer posUserId;
private String userType;
private Integer referencePosno;

private String customerName;
private String Customer;
private String Address;
    private Set<Courses> course = new HashSet<Courses>(0);
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
        public Integer getUserId() {
    return UserId;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
      public Set<Courses> getCourse() {

    return this.course;

}

         // other getter setter method
}
```

Second Entity is like this:

```
              public class Courses {
    private Integer id;
    private String courseType;
    private Set<User> userList = new HashSet<User>();
            private Users user;

    @Id
           @GeneratedValue
        public Integer getId() {

    return id;

     }
      @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false)

      public Users getUsers() {
    return user;

}


}
```

Now the userId is assigned as Foreign key creates the database. How should I insert new in controller?

Can any body tell me how the controller will look like till now I have inserted single row in spring but don't know how to insert multiple dynamic row...because in the form we will have one single row ,dynamic row is generated by using jquery.

Can any one help me out? This is really important and I didn't get any kind of example ,after multiple insert ,the problem is how to view the data and list them in single Jsp,and how to do update?

Comment: @ssedano can i knw wht did u edit.

Comment: Clicking on "edited xx hours ago" will let you know what ssedano edited. Please use proper English too, your shorthand style is.. well,make me (and maybe others) confused a lot

Comment: @viquar I didn't mean to offend you, I reckon that you wrote `hieberbate` instead of hibernate. If you click next to the `edited` (the time) you go to the  modification. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10915042/revisions

Comment: @ssedano no heart feelings bro...u did nothing wrong...but i dint get my answer for the question which i posted.